# How do I "point" container to port 8080?

Tags: docker

I'm learning the ins and outs of Docker from book and I'm asked to:

"Open a web browser and navigate to the DNS name or IP address of the Docker host
that you're running the container from, and point it to port 8080."

I don't understand what I'm asked to do. I've got a container with image running on my machine
but I don't understand how do I get IP address of Docker host ? I can run `docker-machine ip [instance]` but I've got no instance running in the cloud and the container is up locally.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm asked to do ?

```
0c7d84a472ed        test:latest         "node ./app.js"     15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   web1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the container is running locally in your machine (desktop/laptop), open the web browser to the url http://localhost:8080 or https://localhost:8080.

Container port 80 is mapped to 8080 of the node (which is the docker host - the host machine that is running the container. This docker host in your example is localhost itself.

Hence, http://localhost:8080 should work

Phrase "Point to" actually means to open the web page hosted in this context.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the port when running the container by adding flags of `-p <hostport>:<serviceport_inside_container>`

Comment: `docker container run -d --name web1 -p 8080:8080 test:latest`

Comment: ^ that's what I ran. But I noticed instead of 8080:8080 I had 8080:80

Comment: exactly, as mentioned in my answer :) I hope it gave you a good reason to double-check ;)

Comment: Yeah I think I just got to understand how Docker containers expose ports to the public and to apps inside the container. Nice learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how do I get the IP address of Docker host? You have use server IP and port for the specific app or service. find below example.

```
ex: docker run -d --name app1 -p 8080:8080 tomcat ( ServerIpaddress:8080)
    docker run -d --name app2 -p 8081:8080 tomcat ( ServerIPaddress:8081)
```

Note: make sure you have open the port on the security group.